# Django slug No News matches the given query

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, slug

I have a django program:

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from autoslug import AutoSlugField #I installed third party package autoslug

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='title')  
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title',null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title
```

View:

```
def newsDetailView(request, slug):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, slug=slug)

def newsListView(request):
    news_list = News.objects.all()
    #some logic and return news#
     return render(request, 'news/index.html', {
             'news':news
    })
```

url:

```
path('<slug:slug>/', views.newsDetailView, name='detail'),
```

template index.html:

```
<a class="news-list text-dark" href="/{{news.slug}}/">
```

Error:

```
Page not found (404)
No News matches the given query.
```

Comment: In the template, `news` is a list of `News` object so there is no `slug`

Comment: how is your complete html looks like?

Comment: @BrianD thank you for your reply ,but each news should have slug filed, before I use slug,I used ip,and it works href="/{{news.ip}}/"

Comment: Hello @William try to use url like this ```{% url  detail news.slug %}``` if you have an app than try like this ```{% url  app_name:detail news.slug %}```

Comment: @William can you also share the rest of the template?